# Linux won't let me mount an external hard drive as read/write

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, mount, read-write

I try

```
mount -t ntfs -o rw /dev/sdb1 /mnt/exthdd
```

it doesn't give me any response so I presume it succeeded but when I try to touch it, it tells me it's a read-only file system

This is driving me nuts

Comment: /dev/sdb1 on /mnt/exthdd type ntfs (rw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ntfs` is the kernel read-only driver. `ntfs-3g` is the FUSE read/write driver.

Comment: You're the man, that's exactly what I needed.  Thank you