# Mounted Drive is read-only

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, read-only

I am using Pop! OS with Windows 10 dual boot. And I have 1 TB STORAGE disk. But I can't write and delete anything on this disk. For example I write a `mkdir folder` in terminal It says Read-only file system.

How can I write something on this disk on Pop! OS. There is no issue on Windows 10.

[My disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWTBE.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. If the linked duplicates don't help, please [edit] the question and state this fact. The question may be reopened then.

Comment: There's also a remote possibility you're using the kernel driver, not `ntfs-3g`. Please see [this question](https://superuser.com/q/196777/432690).

Comment: Pay special attention to the linked question about shutting down Windows 10 properly for dual-booting. Data-corruption is a real danger if you don't do this.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks, I've disabled the fast startup and it fixed now.